# HttpPostedFileBase is not recognized, but "using System.Web" is

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to define a function which accepts as a parameter an object of type `System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase`.

At the top of my class I included `using System.Web;` and the compiler is not too upset with that `using` statement. (It claims the statement is not necessary, but it is not throwing an error.)

However, the compiler gives the following error when I define a parameter of type 'HttpPostedFileBase': The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Why is the compiler throwing this error? I included the necessary using directive and assembly reference, no?

Comment: What kind of ASP.NET?

Comment: I have this line in the cprosj file:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
I think that means it's ASP.NET 1.1.2?

Comment: Same issue. Latest version for Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to System.Web from the Solution Explorer side panel. Simply adding a `using` statement will not add the reference.

Comment: I think I did that already. If I hadn't, then the compiler wouldn't approve of `using System.Web`, right?

Comment: No, it will still let you write that. It won't throw an error.

Comment: I think what I need to do now is find a nuget package the contains System.Web and enter in the Package Manager Console `Install-Package <name of that blessed package>`, right? I'm having a hard time finding the right the nuget package.

Comment: No you dont need to download any package. Are you on Visual Studio?

Comment: yes. (Apparently just plain "yes" is not a valid comment.)

Comment: Go to Project --> Add Reference --> Assemblies, search for System.Web. Check the box for System.Web. Click Ok and close the window, Done.

Comment: Problem: I don't see the option for "Assemblies." I see Projects, Shared Projects, and Browse.

Comment: I actually have no idea why that tab is missing. That is really weird. Maybe you are using the buggy Visual Studio 2017 version. You should ask a question about why your assemblies tab is missing on Stack.